# Return Response arraylist and 1 attribute

Tags: java, get, httpresponse, jsonobjectrequest

This question is about working with java REST and Jsonobjects. I have a `@Get` method that should return a `Response` and the json code below.
  This method `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.I dont which code I have to write to return the Response + json below.

I think this returns a response +  a list of items.

```
return Response.status(200).entity(arrayListFullOfItems).build()
```

But I dont know how to add the length part(`"length"  :687`) into it.  The length field will be calculated based on a attribute of all the items.

The method should return this:

```
 {
          "item" :[
                       {
                          "id"         : 1,
                          "name"       : "Item1",
                          "bool"       : true,
                          "reserveItem": []
                       },
                       {
                          "id"         : 2,
                          "name"       : "Item2",
                          "bool"       : false,
                          "reserveItem": []
                       }
          ],
          "length"  :687
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible like this: currently you're only returning the list. If you want to return more information, you should wrap the data you want to return in a new object and return that one.

e.g.

```
public class Data {
    private List item;
    private Integer length;
}
```